# Difference in size of class files generated with Eclipse and Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar, java-6

We are trying to automate some cumbersome manual steps in Eclipse while releasing plugins internally , using python .

One of those steps involve generating jar files , but while generating jar files using ant the size of some class files differ (40kb) as compared to the class files generated by eclipse (49kb) while creating jar .

I want to know why we are seeing that difference in size (9kb) and if we proceed with jar created by Ant will it cause any issues in production release .

Ant code is as follows -

```
<project name="abc-tool" default="dist">

<property name="src" value="src" />
<property name="lib" value="lib" />
<property name="main" value="main\resources\images" />
<property name="properties" value="properties\corp" />
<property name="build" location="build" />
<property name="dist" location="dist" />

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build}" />
    <delete dir="${dist}" />
</target>


<target name="init">
    <tstamp />
    <mkdir dir="${build}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}\${main}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build}\${properties}" />
</target>

<target name="copy-non-java-files">
    <copy todir="${build}\${main}" >
        <fileset dir="src\main\resources\images" excludes="**/*.java" />
    </copy>
    <copy todir="${build}\${properties}" >
        <fileset dir="src\properties\corp" excludes="**/*.java" />
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init,copy-non-java-files">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" source="1.6.45" includeantruntime="true">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${java.class.path}/" />
            <fileset dir="C:\Temp\corp_installation\EclipseKepler\eclipse\plugins">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${lib}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="dist" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${dist}" />
     <copy todir="${build}/META-INF">
        <fileset dir="META-INF"/>
     </copy>
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/abc-tool-${DSTAMP}-${TSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}" manifest="${build}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Eclipse by default does not use standard javac but its own compiler (ecj) so maybe that explains it. Also, 1.6?

Comment: @fge is it ok proceed to with the above code ? , moreover we havent migrated to 1.8

Comment: Well, javac does the job just fine, so yes; rather, you have to wonder why Eclipse still insists on ecj